# Which pact is being referred to?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-pact

As the title asks, what is the Pact referred to in the 2012 Movie "[The Pact](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2040560/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)"

I've watched the movie but I don't recall any reference to a pact?  Is it that the sisters agree not to talk about what happens when they were kids? Or is it something between the Mother and her Brother? Or something else entirely

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question after watching this film, as no specific mention is made of a pact throughout the story.

At the risk of turning this thread into a collection of subjective speculation, I thought it referred to a pact between the mother and brother in that she knew the brother was a monster and protected him.

A *'pact of silence'* if you will.